# How to transfer the contents of help(tkinter.Tk()) to a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to transfer the output of `help(tkinter.Tk())` to a python file but for some reason it is not happening.

I wanted to try this without using any `subprocess` module. Following is the code.

```
import tkinter

window=tkinter.Tk()

with open('C:\\Users\\aryan21710\\help_output.txt','a') as f:
    #f.write(help(tkinter.Tk()))
    print (help(tkinter.Tk()),file=f)

with open('C:\\Users\\aryan21710\\help_output.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.split('\n')
        if 'destroy' in line:
            print('DESTROY FOUND IN FOLLOWING LINE:- {0}'.format(line))
```

Comment: Note that `help` usually launches an interactive help file, so it doesn't print to the standard output. In an interactive session, `print(help(tkinter.Tk()))` prints None.

Comment: I recommend using raw strings when working with Windows paths, i.e. instead of `'C:\\Users\\aryan\\test.txt'` you should use `r'C:\Users\aryan\test.txt'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `help()` launches interactive Python and doesn't return anything, you must run it in a subprocess and read its output:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'python3 -c "import tkinter; help(tkinter.Tk())"'
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now you can access `cmd.stdout` to get the lines of the `help()`'s output. Be aware that they're bytes, but you can easily convert these lines to a single multi-line string with:

```
help_text = ''.join(line.decode('utf-8') for line in process.stdout)
```

Comment: i tried using the above code but not able to get the desired output.                                           import subprocess                                                                 
cmd = 'python3 -c "import tkinter; help(tkinter.Tk())"' process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 print (process)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x00000242620CC0F0>
for line in process.stdout:
 print (line)

help_text = ''.join(line.decode('utf-8') for line in process.stdout)
print (help_text)

Comment: @Ary You probably don't have `python3` available on your machine. Maybe you're on Windows, in which case try changing `cmd` to use `python -c` instead of `python3 -c`.

Comment: Thanks Markus.  Yeah i am on windows. Thats the reason, python3 -c wasnt working.   with cmd=python -c , its returning the output.

Comment: @Ary Glad to help :)